# finding second smallest value in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have one mysql table  with the following set of records.

```
Product_id reg_price  sale_price

244         50          40

244         45          40 

244         45           0   

244         40           0
```

I need to find maximum and minimum reg_price, max, min sale_price from this table with the condition that if the sale_price is 0.00 then it should return second highest value than it, i.e 40.

my query is this:

```
SELECT MAX(regular_price) AS max_regular_price, 
       MIN(regular_price) AS min_regular_price, 
       MAX(sale_price) AS max_sale_price, 
       MIN(sale_price) AS min_sale_price
FROM `table` 
where product_id` = 244 LIMIT 1
```

but it gives min_sale_price as 0.00. How should I modify it to get desired result ?

Comment: What was you reasoning for using a LIMIT - MIN,MAX are only going to return a single row anyway - have you tried removing it?

Comment: yes, I removed the limit, but it didn't solve my problem. I need second smallest sales_value from the table if the smallest sales_value is 0.00.

Comment: Can you just add `WHERE sale_price != 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    MIN(NULLIF(sale_price, 0))
FROM `table`
WHERE product_id = 244;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I think you can archive your result is to make multiple queries with a LIMIT 2 select the 2nd result MIN, and MAX are not designed to select the x th value from MIN or MAX.

```
SELECT sale_price AS min_sale_price
FROM `table` 
WHERE product_id` = 244 ORDER BY sale_price LIMIT 2
```

So the second result would be MIN+1

Comment: but then I need to write another query for getting the the value, I want to get min-max reg_price and min-max sale price in the query with the given condition. is it not possible to do so in one query ?

Comment: I do not think so - but I am waiting for a SQL heavy weight to answer.